# Kubernetes grpc http 2error

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, http2, amazon-elb

I deployed a grpc service on eks and expose the service using ingress. I deployed an demo https app, it worked. However, I have a problem with the grpc app. The service is running but when I log the service I get an error.
 The grpc request does not even go to the server. The log is as following

> level=info msg="grpc: Server.Serve failed to create ServerTransport: 
>   connection error: desc = \"transport: http2Server.HandleStreams
>   received bogus greeting from client: \\"GET / HTTP/1.1\\r\\nHost:
>   19\\"\"" system=system

It seems it should receive http2 but it just has `HTTP/1.1`??

For ingress I tried

```
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:xxxx
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: 'routing.http2.enabled=true'
```

for service.yml

```
  annotations:
    service.alpha.kubernetes.io/app-protocols: '{"grpc":"HTTP2", "http": "HTTP2"}'
```

For the service deployed it seems fine. Once I have ingress deployed it keeps have the error above.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if Ingress supports HTTP2/gRPC. If you are using GKE, you could try [ESP](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/get-started-kubernetes-engine)

Comment: It seems alb does not support http2 https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/issues/665  thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use Istio service mesh to solve this problem. Istio virtual service can route HTTP1.1 HTTP2 GRPC traffic 
By setting service port name to grpc or prefixing it with grpc-. Istio will configure the service with HTTP2 protocol